# Getting weekly data from sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has a date column ands values according to dates.Normally if i want to select the data between two dates we use the `BETWEEN` syntax but it brings each day between those 2 values i have given.Is it possible to change it so it brings the dates with sopme interval i have given? For example if do a simple

```
SELECT * FROM METABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2012-06-11' AND '2012-07-11'
```

It should bring me the dates as:

```
2012-06-11 myValue Stuff 
2012-06-12 myValue Stuff 
.
.
.
2012-07-11 myValue Stuff.
```

IS it possible to change it to,

```
2012-06-11 myValue Stuff 
2012-06-18 myValue Stuff 
2012-06-25 myValue Stuff 
.
.
.
Until my end date.
```

So this gives me my weekly values.
How can i achieve that?

Comment: Sounds like you want a GROUP BY paired with DATEPART()'s http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

you could use **group by** with **MIN()** and **SUM()** functions

```
SELECT min(date),sum(col1),sum(col2) 
FROM   METABLE 
WHERE  [DATE] BETWEEN '2012-06-11' AND '2012-07-11'
group by datepart(ww,[DATE])
```

## [Click here for demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7767d/1)

**EDIT1:**

As per your comment, if you want to retrieve only one day from a week. Here as per your example in question, its Monday. So I am using **set datefirst 1** to set it as Monday

```
set datefirst 1
select t.* 
from METABLE t
join
  (SELECT min([date]) as dt
   FROM METABLE 
   group by datepart(ww,[date]))a
on t.[date]=a.dt   

 set datefirst 7
```

## [Demo2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20173/2)

Comment: Well this does the job if you had only one field in the group by syntax.I have more  :) And i dont need sums,my values are all calculated,what i need is just to get the value at that specific date.

Comment: @Sin5k4: That is totally a new question ... :)

Comment: @Sin5k4 Seems like you need you update your question.  You say you dont want sums but you request "weekly totals".  You also say "at that specific date" that seems to also be a new requirement not mentioned in your question...

Answer (score 0):

I think datepart function can help you.
[Datepart function MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)